# How to validate json with avro schema in nodejs which can return list of errors for which data errors occured

Tags: node.js, validation, schema, avro

Below is the code snippet for validating json for an avro schema in nodejs using avro-js module.

```
//import module
var avro = require('avro-js');
// path to avro schema
var type2 = avro.parse('./Person.avsc');
// sample payload
var person = {name: 'Bob', address: {city: 'Cambridge', zip: '02139'}};
// validate command
var status = type2.isValid(person); // Boolean status.
```

--- File person.avsc

```
{
  "name": "Person",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "age", "type": ["null", "int"], "default": null},
    {
      "name": "gender",
      "type": {"name": "Gender", "type": "enum", "symbols": ["FEMALE", "MALE"]}
    },
    {
      "name": "address",
      "type": {
        "name": "Address",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [{"name": "zipcode", "type": "int"}]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In above snippet I get  whether the input payload is valid or not what I want is  which elements is causing this schema validtion error like errorList returned after validation.

Please let me know

Answer (score 4):

It seems the `isValid` function accepts a set of `options` as the optional 2nd argument. Inside those options is an `errorHook` handler you can create. When `avro-js` invokes that `errorHook` it will pass in three params (`path`, `any`, `type`), which you can use to construct a richer error message (specifically the `path` param).

```js
//import module
const avro = require('avro-js')
// path to avro schema
const type2 = avro.parse('./Person.avsc')
// sample payload
const person = {name: 'Bob', address: {city: 'Cambridge', zip: '02139'}}
// validate command
const status = type2.isValid(person, {
  errorHook(path, any, type) {
    console.error(`'${any}' is not a valid value (of type ${type}) for '${path.join(".")}'`)
  }
})

// 'undefined' is not a valid value (of type "Gender") for 'gender'
// 'undefined' is not a valid value (of type "int") for 'address.zipcode'
```

You can still use the returned value of `isValid` (which here is `false`) to drive your logic. *Or* if you're more used to other schema based validators in JavaScript (like [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi), [Spected](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spected), or [Yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup)), you can instead customize your `errorHook` to place those validation errors onto an object in the outer scope:

```js
const has = (key, obj) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)
const validationErrors = {}

type2.isValid(person, {
  errorHook(path, any, type) {
    const dotPath = path.join(".")
    if (!has(dotPath, validationErrors)) {
      validationErrors[dotPath] = []
    }
    validationErrors[dotPath].push(
      `'${any}' is not a valid value of type ${type}`
    )
  }
})

if (Object.keys(validationErrors).length > 0) {
  console.error(validationErrors)
}

// {
//  gender: [ `'undefined' is not a valid value of type "Gender"` ],
//  'address.zipcode': [ `'undefined' is not a valid value of type "int"` ]
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using avsc package and errorHook worked for me only when I used the syntax written lower (guess the same could be with avro-js)

```
schema.isValid(Item.payload, {
    errorHook: (path, val, type) => {
        log.error(`'${val}' is not a valid value (of type ${type}) for '${path.join(".")}'`)
    }
  }
)
```